# Can turf be laid directly over sand?

Tags: landscaping

After removing the pavers From the yard , there is about 100 mm of concrete sand ( very compact ) . What preparation should I do to lay Sir Walter Buffalo turf on top.

Should the sand be just turned with top soil and fertiliser or,
Should I remove the sand completely ( clay underneath ) add soil and fertiliser

Then start the turf process

Comment: Related on Gardening - https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/27503/20139

Comment: Where is this? Australia?

Comment: Concrete sand? You mean hard packed sand? Loosen the sand with a tiller or shovel, add a compost to it, then your form of turf.

Answer (score 1):

Can I lay turf on sand? Yes.

It is better to put an organic fertiliser such as fowl manure, mushroom compost or Dynamic Lifter down first before laying the turf.

This is best incorporated into the soil to a depth of 2-4″ (50-100mm) and will help to hold the moisture for the turf.

The above has been taken form the following source:
[Lawn Care Tips and Advice - Atlas Turf](https://atlasturf.com.au/lawn-care-tips/lawn-care-advice/)